# AspectJ 1.8.8 and higher -noverify not working (java 8 VerfiyError)

Tags: java, aspectj

I'm trying to load a struts 2 application with aspectj 1.8.9, with java 8, but the weaving fails due to Stackmap verification errors - 
When upgrading from AspectJ 1.8.7 to 1.8.8 / 1.8.9, -**noverify** flag stopped working and I've got the exception below:

SEVERE: com/opensymphony/xwork2/config/impl/AbstractMatcher
org.aspectj.weaver.BCException: **Unable to find Asm for stackmap generation (Looking for 'aj.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader'). Stackmap generation for woven code is required to avoid verify errors on a Java 1.7 or higher** runtime
when weaving type com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.AbstractMatcher
when weaving classes
when weaving
at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.LazyClassGen.getJavaClassBytesIncludingReweavable(LazyClassGen.java:703)

How can this be solved? I tried using -verfiy but it doesn't work anymore.

---

**Update**:

`NullPointerException` in `org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.asm.StackMapAdder.getCommonSuperClass()` causes the above errors.

To avoid the `NullPointerException` I've made the following changes to the class:

```
protected String getCommonSuperClass(final String type1, final String type2) {
        ResolvedType resolvedType1 = world.resolve(UnresolvedType.forName(type1.replace('/', '.')));
        ResolvedType resolvedType2 = world.resolve(UnresolvedType.forName(type2.replace('/', '.')));

        if (resolvedType1.isAssignableFrom(resolvedType2)) {
            return type1;
        }

        if (resolvedType2.isAssignableFrom(resolvedType1)) {
            return type2;
        }

        if (resolvedType1.isInterface() || resolvedType2.isInterface()) {
            return "java/lang/Object";
        } else {
            do {
                resolvedType1 = resolvedType1.getSuperclass();

                // ************* My start fix *****************
                if (resolvedType1 == null){
                    return "java/lang/Object";
                }
                // ************* My end fix *******************

                if (resolvedType1.isParameterizedOrGenericType()) {
                    resolvedType1 = resolvedType1.getRawType();
                }
            } while (!resolvedType1.isAssignableFrom(resolvedType2));
            return resolvedType1.getRawName().replace('.', '/');
        }
    }
```

It fixes the errors but I can't tell if there are any other side effects.

---

See - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=514062 (this is the exact same issue)

Comment: I do not understand why you want to use that hacky switch at all. What makes you do that? I never had to use it in many years of using AspectJ. BTW, AspectJ 1.8.10 is the latest version.

Comment: Another question: Do you use compile-time or load-time weaving?

Comment: I'm using load-time weaving. I tried to add this flag because when loading Struts 2 application with AspectJ I'm getting the 'stackmap generation exception'. It also happens in AspectJ 1.8.10

Comment: @kriegaex - during load-time weaving when aspectj is used on struts 2 you get stackmap generation errors. When using aspectj 1.8.7 the VM flag -noverify solves these errors and allows you to work. In aspectj 1.8.8 and above - this flag is ignored and therefore you get the error in the description.

Comment: so in this case, is there a different way to 'tell' the JVM to ignore those errors?

Comment: I think you should try to avoid them, not to suppress them. Obviously AspectJ does not find a class from `aspectjweaver.jar`. Find out why. Is the weaving agent loaded too late, maybe after another agent? How do you start it, via `-javaagent:/path/to/aspectjweaver.jar` or otherwise? The JVM flag does not solve anything, it merely suppresses the problem IMO. Can you share a little [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub, maybe? My goal is to help you solve the root cause of the problem.

Comment: I'm using tomcat and starting it via -javaagent:/path/to/aspectjweaver.jar ,there is only one agent jar, I will try to upload some code to GitHub

Comment: @kriegaex, I've updated the original question with some more information

Comment: Sorry, but hacking an external library is not a reproduceable code sample. This way I cannot help you.

Comment: See - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=514062&GoAheadAndLogIn=1 this is the same issue